# How to get rid of characters from ruby array output?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have array output I am outputting to the Show page like this:

```
@store.products.map(&:title)
```

But the output to the page includes the [" "] that I don't want, like:

```
Product: ["Hair Pins"]
```

How can I get rid of the brackets and quotes? Why isn't it just returning the string without the characters?

I have tried strip, chomp, and those don't work. Is there a regular expression I can use to clip off the brackets and quotes?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide the code used to render the output and I'm sure we can fix this real quick. Where is "Product: " coming from?

Comment: This looks like the output of `p` rather than the output of `to_s`

Comment: Are the brackets in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the products on a single line this should work:

```
@store.products.map(&:title).join(",")
```

So you have a String instead of an Array being rendered

Comment: Sweet! the .join(",") did the trick. Thank you. I had a feeling it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the brackets and quotes by using:

```
["Hair Pins"].gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '').gsub('"', '')
```

Comment: Most likely, the brackets are being added unintentionally. The best solution is to identify where that's happening and not put them there in the first place.